# How do I report the power calculation when I am performing calculations on the whole population?

Tags: statistical-power

I am putting together a bid which states: "you should provide information about both your issued and achieved sample sizes, along with appropriate power calculations".

The dataset I am using has the whole population. Could I say:

"I will be studying the whole population, therefore I do not need to state the power"

And how best to word it?

Comment: In almost every case where people claim they have the whole population, they do not: this claim is usually based on a misunderstanding of the meanings of "population" and "sample" in a statistical analysis (which are subtle).  If you truly have an entire population, then there is no need for statistical estimates, p-values, power calculations, or the like.  On the other hand, you have no basis to draw inferences to anything beyond that population, either: you are engaged in a purely descriptive exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would state it a little differently - people could misinterpret "I do not need".

> I will be studying the whole population. Therefore, power calculations are not applicable and not necessary.